# Boto3 s3 Select CSV to Pandas Dataframe-- trouble delimiting

Tags: pandas, amazon-web-services, csv, amazon-s3, boto3

I am trying to use Boto3 to 'query' a .CSV within an s3 bucket and spit the data into a Pandas Dataframe object.  It is 'working'-- with (almost all of the data) in a single column.

Here is the Python (thanks 20 Chrome tabs and stackoverflow threads):

```
import pandas as pd
import boto3
import io

s3 = boto3.client(service_name='s3',
                  aws_access_key_id = 'redacted',
                  aws_secret_access_key = 'redacted')

#just selecting everything until I get this proof of concept finished
query = """SELECT *
        FROM S3Object"""

obj = s3.select_object_content(
    Bucket='redacted',
    Key='redacted',
    ExpressionType='SQL',
    Expression=query,
    InputSerialization={'CSV': {'FileHeaderInfo': 'Use', 
                                'RecordDelimiter': '|'}},
    OutputSerialization={'CSV': {}})

records = []
for event in obj['Payload']:
    if 'Records' in event:
        records.append(event['Records']['Payload'])
    elif 'Stats' in event:
        stats = event['Stats']['Details']

file_str = ''.join(r.decode('utf-8') for r in records)

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(file_str))
```

This is what the .CSV in the s3 bucket looks like:

```
Field_1
"HeaderA""|""HeaderB""|""HeaderC""|""HeaderD"
"valueA1""|""valueB1""|""valueC1""|""valueD1"
"valueA2""|""valueB2""|""valueC2""|""valueD2"
"valueA3""|""valueB3""|""valueC3""|""valueD3"
.
.
.
"valueAn""|""valueBn""|""valueCn""|""valueDn"
```

And here is my current Dataframe output:

```
HeaderB
------------
HeaderC
HeaderD
valueA1
valueB1
valueC1
valueD1
valueA2
valueB2
valueC2
valueD2
...
valueDn
```

Desired output is 4 columns by n rows (plus headers)
Any ideas on how to fix this?

.
.
.
Edit:

```
InputSerialization={'CSV': {'FileHeaderInfo': 'None', 
                                'FieldDelimiter': '"',
                                'AllowQuotedRecordDelimiter': True
                               }}
```

That got me 95% of the way there.  The pipes were added as columns in the dataframe.  Solution:

```
for col in df.columns:
    if col[0] == '|':
        df = df.drop(col, axis = 1)
```

Edit 2:
This solution works when pulling the entire CSV with SELECT *.
Now that this works, I've moved on to the next proof of concept, which is using a more specific query.  There were some discrepancies with what was returned vs. what I could verify by looking directly at the CSV.  I think this is due to the first line of the CSV being Field_1, followed by the actual header fields and record values.  My current theory is that with this first line removed from the original input, I will be able to field-delimit on the quoted pipe and record-delimit on the newline and get the results I want.  I am reaching out to the team responsible for these s3 dumps to see if the first line can be removed.

Comment: maybe change your delimeter from | to "|" ? on a curious note, have you tried read_csv() with using url location of file in the bucket or just downloading and reading into pandas? I do a lot of reading from s3 but haven't tried query.

Comment: RecordDelimiter': '"|"' --> The value of parameter RecordDelimiter is invalid.

Comment: I am using the query method because I plan to build an application which would only select a handful of rows from a .CSV 1GB + in size

Comment: Ok. Interesting. The delimiter I believe is your issue with the quotes around the pipe. But not sure how to advise you there.

Comment: 'RecordDelimiter': '|',
 'AllowQuotedRecordDelimiter': True

((Output did not change))

Comment: I think the problem is ultimately that there is "Field_1" at the top of the CSV, and then the headers and records underneath

Answer (score 4, accepted):

New csv file

```
Field_1
"HeaderA""|""HeaderB""|""HeaderC""|""HeaderD"
"a_val1""|""bv3""|""1""|""10"
"a_val2""|""bv4""|""1""|""20"
"a_val3""|""bv4""|""3""|""40"
"a_val4""|""bv6""|""4""|""40"

def get_results(query):
    obj = s3.select_object_content(
        Bucket=bucket,
        Key=key,
        ExpressionType='SQL',
        Expression=query,
        InputSerialization={'CSV': {'FileHeaderInfo': 'IGNORE',
                                    'FieldDelimiter': '"',
                                    'AllowQuotedRecordDelimiter': True
                                    }},
        OutputSerialization={'CSV': {}})

    # print(list(obj['Payload']))
    records = []
    for event in obj['Payload']:
        if 'Records' in event:
            records.append(event['Records']['Payload'])
        elif 'Stats' in event:
            stats = event['Stats']['Details']

    file_str = ''.join(r.decode('utf-8') for r in records)

    df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(file_str))
    # df = df.filter(regex='Header')
    return df
```

To get this work, ignore the headers (the first line of file) and then specifically search for it in where/and clause. FIguring out the column positions is the time consuming part.

```
query = '''SELECT s._2, s._6, s._10, s._14 FROM S3Object s where s._6 = 'bv4' or s._6 = 'HeaderB' '''
query = '''SELECT s._2, s._6 FROM S3Object s where s._6 = 'bv4' or s._6 = 'HeaderB' '''

get_results(query)
```

Here are the outputs of the two queries

```
  HeaderA HeaderB  HeaderC  HeaderD
0  a_val2     bv4        1       20
1  a_val3     bv4        3       40

      HeaderA HeaderB
    0  a_val2     bv4
    1  a_val3     bv4
```

Comment: Wonderful!  Thank you.  This got me 95% of the way there.    I will edit OP to reflect changes.  Now I just have to establish a proof of concept more narrow than SELECT *... :)

Comment: Cool. If you do please share. I'm curious if this would help me as well.

Comment: once I tried modifying the SELECT clause in the SQL to narrow my results, I started seeing some problems.  I tried selecting one column / all columns WHERE a certain key LIKE 'xxxx', and had a NaN in one of the cells where I expected a string.  I think what needs to be done is to have the team involved with dumping that CSV modify it such that the current first line does not exist, so that the first line will be the real field names.  Then I should be able to field delimit on a quoted pipe and record delimit on a newline.  I think errors are occurring because the second line of the CSV = heads

Comment: a cleaner input is certainly a better approach but you can get it to work the hard way. see updated answer.

Comment: The 'hard way' is kind of working for me.  I now think the problem I was seeing is related to something else beside the CSV format.  Every occurrence of "NA" (north atlantic) in the "REGION" column is returning "NaN".. Any ideas?

Comment: other than the 'NaN', it is working, as long as I include the header names in the WHERE clause like you did.  Columns with relevant info are somewhat easy to identify, as they're odd numbers 1, 3, 5, etc

Comment: solution found (it is the dataframe interpreting "NA" as NaN).  keep_default_na=False

Comment: that's an interesting find there. good to know it's working for you. i learned something in the process too!